# -catalog silently fails with Saxon, how to fix?

Tags: saxon

I'm running [Saxon-HE 9.8.0.8J](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/saxon/Saxon-HE/9.8.0-8/) together with [xml-resolver 1.2](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2/):

```
$ java -cp saxon.jar:resolver.jar \
  net.sf.saxon.Transform \
  -t \
  -warnings:fatal \
  -catalog:this-file-is-absent.xml \
  -s:a.xml -xsl:a.xsl
```

I'm getting:

```
Checking XML and XSL files...
Loading catalog: file:/this-file-is-absent.xml
Saxon-HE 9.8.0.8J from Saxonica
Java version 1.8.0_40
...
```

Is this how it is supposed to work? Just silently continue if the file is not found? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've stepped this through the Apache catalog resolver, and it emits a message "Catalog does not exist" at debug level 3, but the default debug level is 2, so the message disappears.

In fact it's Saxon that sets the level to 2 (when -t is set) so this is under our control. But it's not easy to find out what the appropriate settings are. Also, I'm very reluctant to modify the resolver's configuration because the Apache code puts configuration details in static variables, which means that any changes you make affect other unrelated parts of the application that happen to be running the same Java VM.

Of course if the failure to find the catalog results in failures to locate some source file, you'll get diagnostics for this.

There are many ways I would like to improve the Apache catalog resolver but I don't particularly want to fork it, because I imagine that testing it after changes is a major undertaking.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is there any chance to pass [`xml.catalog.verbosity`](https://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html) system property directly to Apache resolver? I'm setting it to 10, but Saxon, as I understand it, resets it to either zero or 2. Maybe you can not touch it in case it's already set and `-t` is not specified?

Comment: Any plans on releasing a new version with the fix?

Comment: You can follow progress by tracking the issue at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3725